# Sphinx build breaks on Read the Docs with "module not found" Error but builds fine locally

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to build my documentation on Read the Docs but I am getting a dreaded "Module not found" error.  If I issue `make docs` locally in my project's root, everything builds fine so the "Module not found" error is very strange to me.

I am using the PyPackage Cookiecutter template. Here is my project's relavent portion of its tree:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── authors.rst
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── contributing.rst
│   ├── history.rst
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── installation.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── modules.rst
│   ├── readme.rst
│   ├── scattergrid.rst
│   └── usage.rst
├── requirements_dev.txt
├── scattergrid
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   └── scattergrid.py
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_scattergrid.py
└── tox.ini
```

Below is the successful local build in the same project issuing `make docs` in the root:

```
Running Sphinx v3.0.4
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 9 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 9 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] usage
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] usage
generating indices...  genindex py-modindexdone
highlighting module code... [100%] scattergrid.scattergrid
writing additional pages...  searchdone
copying static files... ... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in _build/html.
python -c "$BROWSER_PYSCRIPT" docs/_build/html/index.html
```

Below is the error from Read the Docs:

```
Running Sphinx v1.8.5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 368, in eval_config_file
    execfile_(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/util/pycompat.py", line 150, in execfile_
    exec_(code, _globals)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/checkouts/latest/docs/conf.py", line 20, in <module>
    import scattergrid
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scattergrid'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 300, in build_main
    app = Sphinx(args.sourcedir, args.confdir, args.outputdir,
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 201, in __init__
    self.config = Config.read(self.confdir, confoverrides or {}, self.tags)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 203, in read
    namespace = eval_config_file(filename, tags)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 380, in eval_config_file
    raise ConfigError(msg % traceback.format_exc())
sphinx.errors.ConfigError: There is a programmable error in your configuration file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 368, in eval_config_file
    execfile_(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/util/pycompat.py", line 150, in execfile_
    exec_(code, _globals)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/checkouts/latest/docs/conf.py", line 20, in <module>
    import scattergrid
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scattergrid'


Configuration error:
There is a programmable error in your configuration file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 368, in eval_config_file
    execfile_(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/envs/latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/util/pycompat.py", line 150, in execfile_
    exec_(code, _globals)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/scattergrid/checkouts/latest/docs/conf.py", line 20, in <module>
    import scattergrid
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scattergrid'
```

Here is the exact line where this error occurs in `docs/conf.py`.

```
import scattergrid
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

This was setup by the cookiecutter template and you can see the absolute path is pointing one level up from the docs folder.  Everything builds on Read the Docs if I don't include `import scattergrid` but of course then I don't have any real documentations so any help would be very appreciated!

Here is `docs/scattergrid.rst` built from the cookiecutter template:

```
scattergrid package
===================

Submodules
----------

scattergrid.cli module
----------------------

.. automodule:: scattergrid.cli
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

scattergrid.scattergrid module
------------------------------

.. automodule:: scattergrid.scattergrid
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:


Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: scattergrid
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: If `scattergrid` is the module to be documented, you are not supposed to import it in conf.py. Sphinx will import the module if `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))` is correct.

Comment: The cookiecutter template makes the directory and module have the same name so it maybe confusing but everything is from the boilerpoint template and I just changes the actual contents of the `scattergrid.py` module but not it's name.  Within `conf.py` it's path is pointing to the scattergrid directory and this allows the template to get `__version__` so the template isn't importing the module but the directory that contains the module (at least as I understand it).

Comment: As I mentioned in my last sentence, not importing scattergrid in `docs/conf.py` does indeed build everything but the documentation doesn't show any module documentation from the module's comments.  If I include it, it builds locally and the html generated has all the modules documentation but breaks on Read the Docs.

Comment: When you build on Read the Docs, without `import scattergrid`, aren't there any errors or log messages? Is it possible that scattergrid has some requirements that are installed on your local machine, but are not stated in requirements.txt?

Comment: I found you on GitHub. Here you import libraries that are not necessarily available on Read the Docs: https://github.com/zstreeter/scatterGrid/blob/master/scattergrid/scattergrid.py#L19.

Comment: OHHHH I see!  So it does find the module fine but Read the Docs cannot find the modules that are imported in the scattergrid module so it says it can't find the scattergrid module.  That's a very confusing error message that lead me the wrong pathway.  So can I add these requirements to my new `docs/requirements.txt` file and ReadTheDocs will be cool?  Or what is the best practice for documentation on Read the Docs that requires other imports?

Comment: I don't use RTD myself, but yes I think it will be cool if you add matplotlib, numpy etc to requirements.txt. I believe this is the best practice, see https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/specifying-dependencies.html.

Comment: It built successfully, thank you!  Though I don't see any of the documentation, I at least know what the issue was and I can work the rest out.  The error had me looking in the wrong direction and I am not sure if I would have thought of the other imported modules without your assistance!

Comment: @mzjn Could one of you post this solution as an answer and accept it?